# How to obtain href attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback, linkbutton

How would I be able to obtain the ID of a asp:LinkButton that has been modified by the master page so that I can simulate a click using javascript/jQuery ?

Normally, with this, I would obtain 'ctl05_butSaveAssociation' as the value for '_id':

```
function ClickSaveButton() {
        var _id = $('a[id$="butSaveAssociation"]').attr("ID");           
        __doPostBack(_id, '');
        return false;
    }
```

This doesn't work, because the ID changes again for some reason, as we can see using FireBug and hovering over the asp:LinkButton we have:

```
<a style="border-style: none; display: inline-block;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl05$butSaveAssociation','')" class="CommandButton" id="ctl05_butSaveAssociation" onclick="SaveAssociation();" tabindex="0">Save</a>
```

So in fact, if I hardcode the right ID, it works with:

```
function ClickSaveButton() {
        var _id = "ctl05$butSaveAssociation";       // hardcoded
        __doPostBack(_id, '');
        return false;
    }
```

How could I implement this dynamically using jQuery?

Comment: Your original code should work... `$=` should make it so that it selects `<a />`s with `id`s that _end with_ `"butSaveAssociation"`, which your control still does. Are you sure you're copying your code correctly into StackOverflow?

Comment: where is the `SaveAssociation` method?

Comment: Yes I am positively sure. Please look at the second excerpt at the top, look at what the postback is sending in parameter, notice the dollar sign instead of an underscore! That is the problem...

Comment: `SaveAssociation` is irrelevant in this case...

Comment: it shouldn't matter though; `"ctl05$butSaveAssociation"` still ends with `"butSaveAssociation"`, so `$=` should still be able to select it. I must be missing something, but I can't see what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the HTML generated ids have `_` (because are genereted based on the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property), the ASP.NET helper methods expects `$`. I really don't know exactly why it can't use the underscore on all cases, but this is it...

One easy thing is just using replace like `_id.replace("_", "$")`. Complete code:

```
function ClickSaveButton() {
    var _id = $('a[id$="butSaveAssociation"]').attr("id");
    __doPostBack(_id.replace("_", "$"), '');
    return false;
}
```

But I'm here thinking... Why you just isn't calling the click event?

```
function ClickSaveButton() {
    $('a[id$="butSaveAssociation"]').click();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Great! That solved the problem! The reason I did not simply use the click event (that's what I have tried originally) is that the click event seemed to be only working on the client side, the .ascx control would reload on the page with the changes done, but as soon as you refresh the page, the changes would be lost because nothing would be saved to the database. This is why I thought about doing a PostBack to the server.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to place a `<span>` around it. Something like this:

```
<span id="button">
   <a style="border-style: none; display: inline-block;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl05$butSaveAssociation','')" class="CommandButton" id="ctl05_butSaveAssociation" onclick="SaveAssociation();" tabindex="0">Save</a>
</span>
```

And then in you jQuery

```
var id = $('span[id="button"]').children().attr('id');
```

That would give you a way to identify the button even if it's id changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ASP.NET 4 or better, you can use `ClientIDMode` to make the IDs stay the same as you typed them:

- http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx
- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40